# Access Cassandra docker container from a different host by static IP

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cassandra, virtualbox, macvlan

I have two vms(Oracle VirtualBox) with Ubuntu 22.04 lts. Bridged network is configured between these vms.

On the first vm i run Cassandra docker container.
My goal is to make it accessible from the second vm with cqlsh **using static ip of that container**.

Making cqlsh connection work using first vm's IP and container's port(9042) was fairly simple, using "**bridge**" driver network in docker.
However, to make container's static IP visible from the second vm i apparently need to use "**macvlan**" type network by setting its parent to the bridge network that both vms are connected to(in my case it's called enp0s8). Relying on [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/macvlan/#bridge-mode)

```
docker network create -d macvlan --gateway 192.168.1.198 --subnet 192.168.1.197/28 -o parent=enp0s8 CASnetwork
```

But this approach makes it so that i can't even ping my container from its host vm.
However i can see that container is using its assigned IP

```
docker exec -it cassandra1 nodetool status

Datacenter: datacenter1

=======================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address        Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 

UN  192.168.1.200  297.98 KiB  256     100.0%            4254dee6-fe6e-49ce-afa6-6cb6561b2bf3  rack1
```

And it's not listening on any ports now.

```
~/Cassandra$ sudo lsof -nPi | grep 90

systemd-r  445 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  19069      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53 

systemd-r  445 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  19070      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  cassandra1:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: cassandra1
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
      - 7000:7000
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra1
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='cassandra-cluster'
      - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=256
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADRESS=192.168.1.200
      - CASSANDRA_START_PRC=true
      - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.200
    networks:
      CASnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.200
    volumes:
      - cassandra-data:/var/lib/cassandra

volumes:
  cassandra-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  CASnetwork:
      name: CASnetwork
      external: true
```

Can someone point me where possibly the problem lies